# how it switch label language in android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working in Eclipse for android app and using googlemaps.

I am trying to change the map labels from English to a different language in the app.

I changed the mobile settings language  accordingly but it didn't help.

I still have English map labels in my app.

Comment: I changed the `locale`. then my google map and facebook's language changed. however, the google plus didn't

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a limitation of Google Maps Android API v2.

I can only suggest posting a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) to add localization support.